# Auto Layout issue with collection view cell

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to create a somewhat basic layout and am having the classic "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" problem. After an hour on it I cannot track it down.

Here is the layout in interface builder:

[image: interface builder]

Please note that no constraints are being added/modified in code. Everything is happening in IB.

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
2015-03-07 19:13:33.044 TwitterStats[4326:209207] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8b700 H:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40(90)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8f910 H:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fb40 UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7f888ad87790'@username'.trailing + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fb90 H:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40]-(14)-[UILabel:0x7f888ad87790'@username']>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f888af29690 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8b700 H:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40(90)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-03-07 19:13:33.045 TwitterStats[4326:209207] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8b210 V:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40(90)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8f450 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ad8f150'Unfollow'(52)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8f8c0 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fa00 V:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40]-(10)-[UITableView:0x7f888b840000]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fc30 V:[UITableView:0x7f888b840000]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7f888ad8f150'Unfollow']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fcd0 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ad8f150'Unfollow']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f888af3cb10 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8b210 V:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40(90)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-03-07 19:13:33.073 TwitterStats[4326:209207] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8f450 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ad8f150'Unfollow'(52)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8f8c0 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fa00 V:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40]-(10)-[UITableView:0x7f888b840000]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fc30 V:[UITableView:0x7f888b840000]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7f888ad8f150'Unfollow']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fcd0 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ad8f150'Unfollow']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f888af3cb10 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8f450 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ad8f150'Unfollow'(52)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-03-07 19:13:33.111 TwitterStats[4326:209207] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac441e0 H:[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610(90)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac4f8e0 H:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac8cd20 UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7f888ac52b00'@username'.trailing + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac48b90 H:[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610]-(14)-[UILabel:0x7f888ac52b00'@username']>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f888af3e030 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac441e0 H:[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610(90)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-03-07 19:13:33.113 TwitterStats[4326:209207] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac29530 V:[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610(90)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac41d40 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ac53e90'Unfollow'(52)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac4f890 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac8b790 V:[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610]-(10)-[UITableView:0x7f888b035400]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac48c30 V:[UITableView:0x7f888b035400]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7f888ac53e90'Unfollow']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac8ae40 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ac53e90'Unfollow']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f888af2ba00 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac29530 V:[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610(90)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-03-07 19:13:33.114 TwitterStats[4326:209207] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac41d40 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ac53e90'Unfollow'(52)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac4f890 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac8b790 V:[UIImageView:0x7f888ac87610]-(10)-[UITableView:0x7f888b035400]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac48c30 V:[UITableView:0x7f888b035400]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7f888ac53e90'Unfollow']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac8ae40 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ac53e90'Unfollow']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f888af2ba00 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0(50)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ac41d40 V:[UIButton:0x7f888ac53e90'Unfollow'(52)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The strange thing is this constraint `<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f888af2ba00 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7f888ac7f2c0(50)]>`, I don't get where it's coming from.

Any idea on how to solve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem yesterday. The NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint you mentioned was *not* the problem. I could not figure out where that constraint comes from, but it seems to be normal for collection view cells.

The problem is that the constraints cannot be satisfied. Take a look at the first set of constraints that are not working:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8b700 H:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40(90)]"
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8f910 H:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70 )>"
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fb40 UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7f888ad87790'@username'.trailing + 10>"
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fb90 H:[UIImageView:0x7f888ad8ce40]-(14)-[UILabel:0x7f888ad87790'@username']>"
```

You have 8 points from the left edge to the image view.
The image view is 90 points wide. You have 14 points from the image view to the username. Then the username is constrained to the trailing margin with 10 points space.

Username is a UILabel and has intrinsic size. Suppose that for a given user it required 40 points to display the username. Your constraints would result in a screen width of 8 + 90 + 14 + 40 + 10 = 162. That would be a very narrow screen! These constraints cannot be satisfied.

The thing to do here is remove this trailing constraint:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f888ad8fb40 UIView:0x7f888ad8cd70.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7f888ad87790'@username'.trailing + 10>"
```

If you are really concerned that the username could be too long, you could try keeping this constraint, but changing it from EQUALS 10 to GREATER THAN OR EQUAL to 10.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. The width of the username isn't involved in the conflict. The autoresizing mask constraint, which is imposed by the table view as the (temporary?) cell width, restricts the width to 50 points, but the image view is wider than that and the listed constraints are enough to cause the conflict, even if the username width were 0. Removing the trailing constraint does relieve the conflict, but changing it to an inequality does not. So, the username might extend off the right and be clipped. Reduce its priority from required to high-but-optional and that would work.

Comment: I don't think the autoresizing mask constraint is the problem, otherwise the image view width constraint of 90 would be enough to cause an error, and removing the trailing constraint on username would not change this.

Comment: The width of the username isn't the problem per se, it's the trailing constraint on the username. I suggested trying an inequality because I think it should work, but I did not try to repro his scenario.

Comment: The image view width constraint would not be enough by itself. There has to be a chain of constraints relating the image view's width (directly or indirectly) to the superview's width (directly or indirectly). The constraints are the equivalent of `|-8-[imageView(90)]-14-[username]-10-|`. This implies a width for the superview of at least 8 + 90 + 14 + 10 == 122, because the username can't have a width less than 0. With just, say, `|-8-[imageView(90)`, with no constraints leading to the superview's trailing edge, the image view width wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You suggested the equivalent of `|-8-[imageView(90)]-14-[username]-(>=10)-|`. So, instead of the required width for the superview being == 122, that just makes it >= 122. Since the conflict is with the autoresizing mask constraint requiring that it be 50, that obviously doesn't help.

Comment: So where is the autresizing mask coming from and how to remove it?

Comment: It's coming from the table view. Evidently, the table view is positioning the table cell view using springs-and-struts, which is perfectly fine. You don't remove it, you work around it. It seems that the table view will, at least temporarily, set the table cell's width to very narrow. That's probably before the table view itself has been laid out to its final size in the window. As I suggested, you can set one of the constraints, probably the trailing one, to an optional priority (anything less than 1000, a.k.a. required).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a UICollectionView in a Storyboard.

The cause for this error is the size of the contentView of the CollectionViewCell. It uses the default size which is (50.0, 50.0). This might be an InterfaceBuilder-Bug.

A fix is to change the priority for your imageView.width (90) and the buttons width (52) to 999.